# How to prevent progress bar from skipping when uploading a sliced file?

Tags: javascript, upload, progress-bar, blob

I'm using an XMLHttpRequest(); in a loop to upload a sliced file.

```
function upload(blobOrFile, part, name, size) {
      var formdata = new FormData();
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      ...
      var parallel_uploads=0;
 }
```

In that function I use following code to display the progress bar:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) { 
          parallel_uploads = parallel_uploads + 1;                                                                        
      }
}
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
          var total_parts = Math.ceil(size / 209715);
          var cur_part = (evt.loaded / evt.total) / total_parts;
          var percentComplete = cur_part + parallel_uploads / total_parts;
          $('#bars progress').val(percentComplete);
      }
}, false);
```

Further information to the xhr status [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp).

The progress bar is skipping, especially when uploading small files. In Chrome it skips forwards and backwards even more obvious than in Firefox. I think the problem is that the detection of the parallel uploads went wrong. I tried all xhr states and nothing worked.

So how to get the correct amount of uploaded Bytes from all the blobs?

Answer (score 0):

Well I used following so that it doesn't skip too much when uploading small Files:

```
if(total_parts>20){
   //the code from above
}
else{                                                                            
   percentComplete = parallel_uploads / total_parts;
}
```